# How can I set overflow and can use with touch (mobile phone)

Tags: css

I've CSS like this :

```
.editTable-body {
    width: 100%;
    height:140px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
    .editTable-body:hover{
        overflow:auto;
    }
```

and it does not work on mobile phone screen, when I test touch can not scroll. How can I scroll when touch in phone?

Answer (score 0):

Check `overflow:scroll`, may be it will work.

Comment: The problem is not with the `overflow` property.  The problem is with the `:hover` selector because you cannot hover on a touch-screen.

Comment: Yeah, I think the problem is on `:hover` it's not `overflow`